# Division in VHDL (int/float)

Tags: math, floating-point, binary, vhdl, division

I want to divide two numbers(16-bit binary) in VHDL in 1 cycle (combinational circuit). Numerator is an integer. Denominator is a float. Result should be float.  What algorithm do i use to perform the division.

Please help

Comment: Do you need to do the division in one cycle, or to complete one division per cycle? Many floating point dividers are pipelined, so that they can produce a result per cycle without making the cycle time long enough to do a division in one cycle.

Comment: How long is your clock cycle?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an entity that does what you want (if I understand the question correctly):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.float_pkg.all;

entity integer_by_float_division is
    port (
        numerator: in signed(15 downto 0);
        denominator: in signed(15 downto 0);
        result: out float(6 downto -9)
   );
end;

architecture rtl of integer_by_float_division is
    subtype float16 is float(6 downto -9);
    signal numerator_float: float16;
    signal denominator_float: float16;
begin
    numerator_float <= to_float(numerator, numerator_float);
    denominator_float <= to_float(denominator, denominator_float);
    result <= numerator_float / denominator_float;
end;
```

Comment: I think the OP means "IEEE754 single precision" when they said "float", so the denominator and out probably need to be `float32`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.  Is there any reason that you need to do it in 1 clock cycle?  The only way to get close would be to use a look-up table, but you would have to sacrifice some precision on the output.

Comment: Its part of my project, where I need to perform division in each step of it. So I cannot give more time for division.

Comment: What clock frequency are you running at?